How to embed an SFSymbol into an AttributedString in SwiftUI
I'm curious, is there a way to embed an SFSymbol into an AttributedString?
I would like to be able to include an SFSymbol in a string that has styling applied to it. To illustrate, in the following example, I'd like the "Hello, world!" to be blue, and the globe icon to be red. Using LocalizedStringKey as I have done below lets me embed the SFSymbol in the Text, but I don't have styling control over the parts as I would with an AttributedString.
struct ContentView: View {
    // I'd like to use AttributedString instead.
    var string: LocalizedStringKey {
        "Hello, world! \(Image(systemName: "globe"))"
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(string)
    }
}

If there's a different way (not using AttributedString) of achieving the same result, that would probably be appreciated too!

If you don't need to consider localisation problems like changing the position of the image within the text depending on locale, the simple solution of concatenating Texts (koen's answer) can be used.

The SwiftUI attribute scope does not include the attachment attribute or anything similar, so SwiftUI cannot display an AttributedString with attachments. LocalizedStringKey probably uses a different system from AttributedStringKey.
What you can do instead is use UIKit/AppKit to display the string (their attribute scopes support attachment). For example, here is a UIViewRepresentable modified from Asperi's answer here.
struct LabelView: View {
    let text: AttributedString

    @State private var height: CGFloat = .zero

    var body: some View {
        InternalLabelView(text: text, dynamicHeight: $height)
            .frame(minHeight: height)
    }

    struct InternalLabelView: UIViewRepresentable {
        let text: AttributedString
        @Binding var dynamicHeight: CGFloat

        func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UILabel {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.numberOfLines = 0
            label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
            label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
            label.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)

            return label
        }

        func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: Context) {
            uiView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(text)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                dynamicHeight = uiView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: uiView.bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)).height
            }
        }
    }
}

This implementation resizes itself to fit the content and also works in a ScrollView. You may need a slightly different implementation depending on your needs.
Instead of using a dynamicHeight binding, also consider overriding sizeThatFits if you are on iOS 16+ (in which case you can put everything in LabelView and don't need InternalLabelView).
struct LabelView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let text: AttributedString

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UILabel {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        label.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)

        return label
    }
    
    func sizeThatFits(_ proposal: ProposedViewSize, uiView: UILabel, context: Context) -> CGSize? {
        uiView.sizeThatFits(.init(width: proposal.width ?? .infinity, height: proposal.height ?? .infinity))
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: Context) {
        uiView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(text)
    }
}

To support localisation, you need some kind of placeholder substring. Here is an example:
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.locale) var locale
    var body: some View {
        LabelView(text: localizedAttributedStringWithImage("Hello @@@ World", images: ["@@@": "globe"]))
    }
    
    // images is a dictionary with placeholders as keys and system image names as values
    func localizedAttributedStringWithImage(_ string: String.LocalizationValue, images: [String: String]) -> AttributedString {
        var attributedString = AttributedString(localized: string, locale: locale)
        // adding some random coloring just as an example
        // remember to use UIColors because we are displaying this using UIKit
        attributedString.foregroundColor = UIColor.blue
        for (placeholder, image) in images {
            guard let range = attributedString.range(of: placeholder) else { continue }
            var attachment = AttributedString(NSAttributedString(attachment: .init(image: UIImage(systemName: image)!)))
            attachment.foregroundColor = UIColor.red
            attributedString.replaceSubrange(range, with: attachment)
        }
        return attributedString
    }
}



Wow! Thank you! There's a lot packed into that. Just perfect. Thanks, Sweeper!

Another approach.
From your question: "… include an SFSymbol in a string that has styling applied to it. To illustrate, in the following example, I'd like the "Hello, world!" to be blue, and the globe icon to be red."
You could try this, splitting the string in two parts.
struct ContentView: View {
    var string: LocalizedStringKey {
        "Hello, world!"
    }
    
    var symbol: LocalizedStringKey {
        "\(Image(systemName: "globe"))"
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(string).foregroundColor(.blue) +
        Text(symbol).foregroundColor(.red)
    }
}

Result:


Oh, this is a much simpler solution for many solutions. Thanks! Sweeper's solution may still be needed for some contexts, but I think this should be the first option people try.

@CuriousJorge Yeah, this solution doesn't work well if you want to localise the string. I had assumed that you wanted to localise the string e.g. change where the image, is depending on locale. But if you don't need to consider localisation, this is the way to go.

You can use an AttributedString and embed an SFSymbol as an attachment.
import SwiftUI

struct ContectView: View{

var attributedString: AttributedString {
    var attributed = AttributedString("Hello, world! ")
    attributed.foregroundColor = .blue // 
    if let sfSymbol = try? AttributedString(Image(systemName: "globe"), options: .init()) {
        var sfSymbolStyle = AttributeContainer()
        sfSymbolStyle.foregroundColor = .red
        attributed.append(sfSymbol.settingAttributes(sfSymbolStyle))
    }
    
    return attributed
}

var body: some View {
    Text(attributedString)
        .font(.system(size: 18))
        
}

}


Thanks for the suggestion! The above code doesn't work for me, AttributedString seems to be expecting a LocalizedStringResource as the first argument. Do you have an extension that makes the above work?

You're absolutely right—AttributedString expects a LocalizedStringResource as the first argument. To work around this, you can use the following extension, which allows you to embed images (like SF Symbols) into an AttributedString. This should make the code functional.
import SwiftUI

extension AttributedString {
    init(image: Image, baselineOffset: CGFloat = 0) {
        let uiImage = image.asUIImage()
        let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
        attachment.image = uiImage
        attachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: baselineOffset, width: uiImage.size.width, height: uiImage.size.height)
        
        let attributedImage = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
        self.init(attributedImage)
    }
}

extension Image {
    func asUIImage() -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 18, height: 18))
        return renderer.image { _ in
            self
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 18, height: 18)))
        }
    }
}


Thanks very much! I tried combining your two answers to get something working, but there were still some errors. I think that I managed to fix all of them except for solving the call to draw in asUIImage. I may have made some mistakes. It would be most helpful if you could edit your first answer to include the extensions above, along with whatever fixes are needed, so we can be sure we understand you correctly.
